# Should UI tests be run on a build server or after deployment?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing

Should end to end tests be run at build time (running the application on the build server), or after deployment? I have not yet found a solid answer for which one is the standard.

**Edit**

I mean after deploying either to QA/SIT/UAT etc... vs. just running it on a build server without fully deploying it.

Comment: depends on the requirements -- must the build (continuous integration) job be considered a failure if the functional (ui) tests do not pass?

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of having a build server is to create a single build of the current source code, of which you run tests and make sure that things work before you deploy them. I don't know why anyone would want to run tests after then have been deployed. What happens if you find a bug? You going to roll back the deployment? Always test before deployment.

Ideally, you would have a build environment that mimics your production environment that will allow you to run tests in a "deployed" environment. It's the reason that you have a development/staging/production servers.

Comment: depends on the maturity of the team/org -- the whole point of a build  server is not "to run tests" although it is an additional/desirable capability if considering it from a continuous delivery point of view.  from a stack overflow perspective, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099133/what-is-the-point-of-a-build-server

Comment: it is also not "to create a single source of code" -- that is the purpose of source control like svn, git, etc.

Comment: Also, running tests is not required in the context of "the whole point of having a build server" -- see the other SO link in comment above. Not trying to be pedantic, I swear!